# Node adding additional brackets to json post body

Tags: json, node.js

Im sending post requests from a .NET application to a node REST api with a controller named 'createPdf'

The .NET code im using to send the post requests seems to be working fine, im creating a json object using SerializeObject and then using UrlEncode to encode the json and then sending it off in a post request.

```
 Dim postjson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(article)
 Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("url")
 request.Method = "POST"
 Dim postData As String = WebUtility.UrlEncode(postjson)
 Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 //go off and send the post request
```

this seems to produce valid json in this format -

```
{
    "source": "le sauce",
    "subTopic": "le subtopic",
    "Title": "le title",
    "Body": "le body",
    "refs": "le refs",
    "lastUpdated": "19/12/2016 11:23:56"
}
```

but when I send the json and try and parse the json with the code below in my node controller it seems to add additional brackets and colons to the json.

Node controller

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");

var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body); 
   res.status(200).send('lol');   
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is the invalid json that is output from the console.log(req.body)

```
{ '{
    "source”:”le sauce“,
    ”subTopic”:”le subtopic“,
    ”Title”:”le title“,
    ”Body”:”le body“,
    ”refs”:”le refs“,
    ”lastUpdated":"19/12/2016 11:23:56"
}': '' }
```

for some reason extra brackets, colons, quotes, etc have been added to the json at some point and made the json invalid, Im pretty sure its not happening on the .NET side and must be happening when Node tries to handle the post request but I cant figure out where.

any ideas as to how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending JSON, then this is incorrect:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

as is this on the server side:

```
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

That quite clearly says you're sending URI-encoded form data, not JSON, and telling `body-parser` to decode URI-encoded form data, not JSON.

Send the right content type:

```
request.ContentType = "application/json"
```

...and use the right parser:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

(Note that you can use multiple parsers if you have endpoints that expect URI-encoded form data and others that expect JSON; `body-parser` will figure it out from the content type.)

Comment: that makes the req.body output an empty json object for some reason

Comment: that has worked now, The additional brackets and such aren't being added anymore but something even more odd is happening, in the json all of the quotes have been replaced with apostrophes making the json invalid again

Comment: @scriptss: By the time you receive it, it isn't JSON anymore; that's the **point** of body-parser, it *parses* the *body* for you. If you're doing `console.log(req.body)`, you're dumping out an object, and node will use its default object output (for instance, `object { foo: 'bar' }`).

Answer (score 0):

Set your Content-Type to `application/json`. Since you're trying to send JSON but actually sending url-encoded data, Node cannot decode it correctly. Then, try this code:

```
Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url")
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"

Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter = new StreamWriter 
(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ())
Dim jsonData As String = "{'source':'lesauce','subTopic':'lesubtopic','Title':'letitle','Body':'lebody','refs':'lerefs','lastUpdated':'19/12/201611:23:56'}"
streamWriter.Write (jsonData)
streamWriter.Close ()

Get Response here
```